# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null phaser

Tags: javascript, undefined, phaser-framework

This down below is a simplified version of my code where the menu happenes. I keep getting this error.It happenes when i click on the play button:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null
```

I know thats when i check if sprite play is bieng clicked but cant figure out problem.

Here is the picture:
[image]

[JsFiddle Format](http://jsbin.com/peyadiw/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
  preload: function() {
                game.load.image('background', 'http://s1.postimg.org/nqynk9tkv/starfield.png')
                game.load.image('play-back', 'http://icon-park.com/imagefiles/movie_play_black.png');

            },
            create: function() {
                this.backgroundImg = this.game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 500, 550, 'background')

                this.gameText = game.add.text(game.world.centerX-190, game.world.centerY - 150, "Space Invaders", {
            font: "60px Times New Roman",
            fill: "#ccccb3",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            stroke: "white",
            strokeThickness: 2.5
        });

 /*       // this.gameText.anchor.setTo(0.5)
        this.gameText.angle =
*/
        play = game.add.sprite(120,280,'play-back')
        play.scale.setTo(0.5);
         game.physics.arcade.enable(play);
        play.events.onInputDown.add(this.start, this);

            },
            update: function() {
                this.backgroundImg.tilePosition.y += 5;


            },
            render: function() {

            },
            start: function() {

                game.start.main('main')
            }

        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From phaser docs: ["The Input-related events will only be dispatched if the Sprite has had inputEnabled set to true"](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Events.html)

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: http://perplexingtech.weebly.com/game-dev-blog/using-states-in-phaserjs-javascript-game-developement